# Applying the conversions in the converters dictionary after a DataFrame has been created in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, converters

I have the following line which reads a CSV and creates a Data Frame applying my custom converters as expected:

```
csv_file_raw = read_csv(f'{directory}\{filename}', converters=converters)
```

However I wish to remove all blank rows from the Data Frame which I have accomplished with the following line after the Data Frame has been created:

```
csv_file = csv_file_raw.dropna(how="all")
```

My issue now is that the converters have parsed some of the values into empty strings which the `dropna` function doesn't interpret as an 'N/A' value.

The blank rows are removed if I do not include the conversion in the `read_csv` function like so:

```
csv_file_raw = read_csv(f'{directory}\{filename}')
csv_file = csv_file_raw.dropna(how="all")
```

Now that I have removed the empty rows, is there an easy way I can apply the converters dictionary to the Data Frame or can this only be achieved when it is initially read from the CSV?

Answer (score 0):

Replace all empty string by `np.NaN` and then use `dropna`

```
csv_file_raw = read_csv(f'{directory}\{filename}', converters=converters)
csv_file = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.NaN, regex=True).dropna(how="all")
```

Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': ["1", "", np.NaN], 'c2': ["1", "", "2"]})
print (df)
df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.NaN, regex=True).dropna(how="all")
print (df)
```

Output:

```
    c1 c2
0    1  1
1        
2  NaN  2

    c1 c2
0    1  1
2  NaN  2
```

Comment: Isn't that reversing the work of the converters though? I only want to remove completely blank lines while retaining the conversions that have been applied

Comment: No. you run the converters first, all the empty string resulted out of converters will be replaced by NaN (I am assuming that converters does not effect already existing NaNs) and the finally remove all NaNs. There are other way to do this but this is closes to what you already have.

Comment: Yeah some of the existing NaN are converted to an empty string in certain columns